# display the map value if key exists in angular 5 html

Tags: angular, typescript, dictionary, rxjs

In the `component` file a map is created - `tempDAMap`:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
export class AComponent implements OnInit {
  tempDAMap = new Map();
    /** Onchange */
  selectedName(pName: any): void {
    this.service.getPAData(pName).subscribe( (data) => {
      if (data.length > 0 && data != '' && data != null) {
    this.savedData = data;
    this.tempDataStatus = true;
    this.savedData.forEach(function(assessData) {
      this.tempDAMap.set(assessData.qId, assessData.ansSelected);
    })
      }
      else {
        this.tempDataStatus = false;
      }
    },
    (error) => {} )
  }
}
```

In the HTML file, there is a outer for loop containing `QuestionId` and inside a map (subset) to check if the `QuestionId` exists in it and display the value from map `tempDAMap`.

```
    <div *ngFor="let QA of Questions">
      <div>  <label> {{ques.desc}} </label>
        <div *ngIf="tempDataStatus === true">
 /** Check if tempDAMap contains Id (from Questions- outer for loop)*/
        <div *ngIf="tempDAMap.has(ques.questionId)"> 
          <p> {{ }} </p>  /** display the map value  */
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I'm unable to check if the key exists and display the map value.

> ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read property 'tempDAMap' of undefined.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```js
this.savedData.forEach(function(assessData) {
 this.tempDAMap.set(assessData.qId, assessData.ansSelected);
});
```

You need to use arrow functions:

```js
this.savedData.forEach((assessData) => {
  this.tempDAMap.set(assessData.qId, assessData.ansSelected);
});
```

In javascript, `function` is a keyword that represents an action but it ***also has similar behavior to the `class` keyword***, playing the role of a class constructor when it appears after another keyword: **new** (eg. `new function(...) {...}`). Originally this even was the way of instantiating objects in javascript.

Because of that, when you use the **`function`** keyword you set a scope, and the `this` inside it refers to the function itself, as a consequence of its class constructor behavior.

The above behavior can be avoided by one of two ways:

1. **Old school:** Save the outside scope in a temporary variable so it can be used inside of the function (`that` is a common variable name used for this task):

```js
const that = this;
this.savedData.forEach(function(assessData) {
 that.tempDAMap.set(assessData.qId, assessData.ansSelected);
});
```

2. **Arrow functions:** To avoid trapping the meaning of `this` inside the function, you can avoid the `function` keyword when creating a function. Instead of that, you can use the *arrow function* notation (*lambda functions* in other programming languages) to define your functions. By doing that the `this` keyword inside the body of the arrow function will refer to the outside scope (some people like to say that you *bring the outside scope to the function scope*).

Comment: But, how to display the map value ??

Comment: Just use `{{tempDAMap.get(ques.questionId)}}`